# ListBox SourceUpdated's event handler is not called in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to run event handler when `DeviceListItem` is updated. But, The evnet handler is not called even though data is updated on view.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="DeviceListItem" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceListItems, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     SourceUpdated="OnDeviceListItemsUpdated">
```

**View**

```
private void OnDeviceListItemsUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // to do
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ObservableCollection<Device> mDeviceListItems;
public ObservableCollection<Device> DeviceListItems
{
    get { return mDeviceListItems;  }
    set { mDeviceListItems = value; 
          RaisePropertyChangedEvent("DeviceListItems"); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use CollectionChanged of ObservableCollection

```
 DeviceListItems.CollectionChanged += itemDisplayList_CollectionChanged;

  void itemDisplayList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I solved it without `sourceUpdated` event handler.

```
    INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel = (INotifyPropertyChanged)DataContext;
    viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnDeviceListItemsUpdated;
}

private void OnDeviceListItemsUpdated(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```